# how to copy tweens from timeline to a class (simple solution)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, adobe

after a few tries I managed to copy motions from the timeline to be used inside a class.
all you have to do is copy the code inside of your class function and move "import" lines up to their places. and move "AnimatorFactory" declaration up to the class body. and if you like to call the animation with a function move "ani.addTarget(this, 1);" to a new public function.

here is my final code I'll be using as an example:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.motion.AnimatorFactory;
import fl.motion.MotionBase;
import fl.motion.Motion;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class mo extends MovieClip {
    var ani:AnimatorFactory;
    public function mo() {
        var mo:MotionBase;
        if (mo == null) {
            mo = new Motion();
            mo.duration = 30;

            mo.overrideTargetTransform();

            mo.addPropertyArray("x", [0,10.6897,21.3793,32.069,42.7586,53.4483,64.1379,74.8276,85.5172,96.2069,106.897,117.586,128.276,138.966,149.655,160.345,171.034,181.724,192.414,203.103,213.793,224.483,235.172,245.862,256.552,267.231,277.931,288.621,299.31,310]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("y", [0,0.689655,1.37931,2.06897,2.75862,3.44828,4.13793,4.82759,5.51724,6.2069,6.89655,7.58621,8.27586,8.96552,9.65517,10.3448,11.0345,11.7241,12.4138,13.1034,13.7931,14.4828,15.1724,15.8621,16.5517,17.2407,17.931,18.6207,19.3103,20]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("scaleX", [1.000000]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("scaleY", [1.000000]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("skewX", [0]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("skewY", [0]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("rotationConcat", [0]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("blendMode", ["normal"]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("cacheAsBitmap", [false]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("opaqueBackground", [null]);
            mo.addPropertyArray("visible", [true]);

            ani = new AnimatorFactory(mo);
            ani.transformationPoint = new Point(0.500000,0.500000);
        }
    }
    public function strt() {
        ani.addTarget(this, 1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: and you can pass "repeat times" to the function if needed.

Answer (score 1):

solved by moving var ani:AnimatorFactory; up and declare it outside of the function ^_^